# Constructing any function $\{1 \dots n\} \rightarrow \{1 \dots k\}$ using functions $\{1 \dots n \} \rightarrow \{1,2\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is: i'm having some function $\{1 \dots n\} \rightarrow \{1 \dots k\}$ is it possible to show bijection between functions of type $\{1 \dots n\} \rightarrow \{1 \dots k\}$ and some function (or their product, composition or something like that) that takes some function or $\{ 1 \dots n \}$ as domain and $\{1,2\}$ as counterdomain?

I only came up with construction when $k$ is a power of 2. 
For example let's take $k=4$ then our constructed function would be: 
$f : f' \rightarrow \{1,2\}$ 
and $f' : \{1 \dots n \} \rightarrow \{1,2\}$
Idea is similiar to binary search. My problem is when $k$ is not a power of two. Can we somehow construct those functions when $k$ is not a power of two? My question is more theoretical than practical, it is I don't need efficient construction of those functions; can be any.

I'd greatly appreciate some help on this.

Comment: There are $k^n$ such functions from $[n]\to [k]$. There are $2^n$ functions $[n]\to[2]$. If $k>2$, then there are too many functions in the first case for there to be a bijection. (Where $[m]=\[1,2,3,\dots,m\}$.)

Comment: Presumably, you want a bijection between the set of $[n]\to [k]$ and the set $[N]\to[2]$ for some $N$ depending on $k$ and $n$?

Comment: If that is the case, then my first comment and unique factorization of integers means that $N$ exists if and only if $k$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: It doesn't really have to be just $[N] \rightarrow [2]$ it can be any construction like: function of pair of functions, but with counterdomain $[2]$

Comment: It still doesn't matter - the number of tuples of functions, the $i$th being $[N_i]\to [2]$, is just the number of functions from $[N_1+\cdots + N_m]\to[2]$.

Comment: Oh, okay - thank you for it then:-)